Trying to loosen bottom screw on Schlage front door handleset fixture
We are trying to replace our front door handle.  However, we have run into an issue on loosening the bottom screw on the handle latch fixture. On one side there is a Philips head screw head, and on the other a button head that just spins with the screw. We are unable to loosen the screw to take the fixture off. Any ideas?

Locking pliers on the button/cap nut, or some times just pulling on the other side will grip enough.  Angle grinder or hack saw will remove the button if pliers/pulling do not work.

And if the vise grips won't actually unscrew the nut, they'll often simply shear the bolt!

Place a hammer against the button and tap on the screw end a bit.  That may loosen the screw enough that it can be undone easily. If it's still seized  there are other options:
a: grasp the button with locking pliers.
b: drill holes into the button, or cut a slot, and use a pin spanner or flat screwdriver.
If the phillips screw still won't loosen. saw, drill or grind off the philips head and extract the button with the screw shank still attached
